# Instantiate creates multiple clones in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have the following code:

```
public Rigidbody2D ball;
Vector2 sp = new Vector2(0f, 2.1f);

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")) {
        SpawnBall();           
        DestroyBall();
    }
}
void SpawnBall()
{
    Instantiate(ball, sp, transform.rotation);
}

void DestroyBall()
{
    if (ball.transform.position.y >= -5.7f)
    {
        Destroy(ball);
    }
}
```

and the code is supposed to generate a new ball every time when "w" is pressed, but for some reason it creates multiple clones and it crashes the engine. How can I create a single clone only?

And also the destroy method doesn't do anything, although it should remove the clone when it passes -5.7 on the y-axis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new script named "SpawnRigidbody" and copy and paste the below code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnRigidbody : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Rigidbody2D ball;
    Vector2 sp = new Vector2(0f, 2.1f);

    void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")) {
            SpawnBall();
        }
    }

    void SpawnBall()
    {
        Debug.Log ("spawn");
        GameObject go = Instantiate(ball, sp, transform.rotation).gameObject;
        go.AddComponent<DestroyAfterPosition> ();
    }
}
```

Now create another script named "DestroyAfterPosition" and copy and paste the below code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyAfterPosition : MonoBehaviour 
{

    void Update ()
    {
        if (transform.position.y <= -5.7f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Create an empty game object and attach the SpawnRigidbody and then assign your ball in the inspector.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems with your `Destroy()` statement. First, it is destroying `ball` which is the `Rigidbody2D`. You will instead want to destroy the gameobject attached to the ball:
 `Destroy(ball.gameObject);`

Second, you are trying to destroy the ball immediately after it is created, but only if `y>=-5.7f`. I think instead what you are looking to do is continuously check if the ball is above that point and destroy it if it is. Since you are creating multiple balls, they will all need their own check, which means you need to create a script for the ball prefab and in the `Update()` check its position and Destroy(gameObject) as necessary.

I think you may want to declare ball as a GameObject at the beginning of your script as well, so you are instantiating a gameobject and not just a Rigidbody2D:
`public GameObject ball;`

Comment: I tried, but still the same. I get an infinite amount of clones and they are not destroyed.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please check it out, as well as Joe Sewell's and let me know if that gets you any where.

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) creates a clone of the provided object, so each time it is called a new object is created. [`MonoBehaviour.Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) is called every frame, which means it's called at least 30 times per second (usually 60 or more on a PC).

So 30+ times per second, your code checks if the `w` key is held down, and, if so:

- A clone of `ball` is created
- Destroy the original `ball` if it is beyond -5.7 on the y-axis.

Thus, you're creating 30+ ball clones per second, and none will be deleted (because the `DestroyBall` method only looks at the original ball, not the clones).

If you want to work with the cloned object, assign the result of `Instantiate` to a field:

```
ballClone = Instantiate(ball, sp, transform.rotation);
```

Then you can [check if `ballClone` exists](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) and skip the `SpawnBall` call if the clone already exists. You can also use `ballClone` in the `DestroyBall` method.

[ryemoss' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020553/2137382) seems like it's 
 also important. This answer is just based on looking at your code and the public Unity docs; I don't have a lot of experience with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Your destroy call is being called once, and only immediately after creating the object.

So it's currently doing this...

1. User clicks button...
2. Create ball...
3. Check to see if the ball is a certain height. It's not, so ignore...
4. Ball drops down based on gravity or whatever force compels it.

... and is never deleted.

If you want the ball to be destroyed when it reaches a certain point, either...

1. Have SpawnBall return the game object, which you store and check / delete later in Update,

...or...

2. Create a script that just checks the object's transform.position and blows up if it's where it needs to be. Attach that to the prefab of the ball you're creating a duplicate of.